# How to reference figures that are in the supplementary content in main text?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, subfloats

I am writing a scientific paper using LaTeX and want to reference supplementary figures that are in a different document. How can I do this?

For example. In my main document I want to write something like this:

```
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../FitData}}

\begin{document}
Here I want to reference a figure that is in my supplementary content \cref{fig:model_selection_criteria}

\end{document}
```

While in my supplementary content I have a figure:

```
\begin{document}
    %% BIC and RSS distributions

    \begin{figure*}[t]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../FitData/ModelSelectionGraphs/Histogram_smad7_reproduced_BIC}
        \label{fig:model_selection:BIC}
        \caption{BIC}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../FitData/ModelSelectionGraphs/Histogram_smad7_reproduced_RSS}
        \label{fig:model_selection:RSS}
        \caption{RSS}
        \end{subfigure}
    \label{fig:model_selection_criteria}
    \caption{Distribution of Bayesian information criteria (BIC) and RSS values per model}
    \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `xr` package and say `\externaldocument[supp-]{supplementstuff.tex}` in order to load the reference information from the external document `supplementstuff.tex`, then apply `\ref{supp-fig...}` or `\cref{supp-fig...}` in order to get the cross-reference.

Compile the supplement file first.

Please note, that `\label` must be placed **after** `\caption`, not before!

*mainfile.tex*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\graphicspath{{../FitData}}

\externaldocument[supp-]{supplementstuff}

\begin{document}  
Here I want to reference a figure that is in my supplementary content \cref{supp-fig:model_selection_criteria}
\end{document}
```

*supplementstuff.tex*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cleveref}



\begin{document}
    %% BIC and RSS distributions

    \begin{figure*}[t]
      \centering
      \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../FitData/ModelSelectionGraphs/Histogram_smad7_reproduced_BIC}
        \caption{BIC}
        \label{fig:model_selection:BIC}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../FitData/ModelSelectionGraphs/Histogram_smad7_reproduced_RSS}
        \caption{RSS}
        \label{fig:model_selection:RSS}
      \end{subfigure}
      \caption{Distribution of Bayesian information criteria (BIC) and RSS values per model}
      \label{fig:model_selection_criteria}
    \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```