# reference external figures from supplementary inside overleaf

Tags: overleaf, external-files, xr, external

I try to reference external figures from the supplementary information inside the main text.
[How to reference figures that are in the supplementary content in main text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397810/how-to-reference-figures-that-are-in-the-supplementary-content-in-main-text) describes an approach I try to sue. However, on overleaf:

https://www.overleaf.com/read/gwrswfmpqskp

this does not work. XR complains that:

```
no supplementarystuff.aux / labels not imported
```

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf

is indeed answering my question